# UML Associacion in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, connection, uml

I created simple UML diagram, it is about movies in cinema. One movie can be emitted multiple times.

[image]

And I wrote a XSD codes:

- emission.xsd

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  ```

  ```
  <element name="emission" type="tst:emissionType"/> 
  <complexType name="emissionType">
      <sequence>
          <element name="idOfMovie" type="integer" use="required" />
          <element name="dateOfEmission" type="string" use="required" />
          <element name="idOfHall" type="integer" use="required" />
      </sequence>
      <attribute name="idOfEmission" type="integer" use="required"/>
  </complexType>
  </schema>
  ```
- movie.xsd

  ```
  <element name="movie" type="tst:movieType"/> 
  <complexType name="movieType">
      <sequence>
          <element name="title" type="string" use="required" />
          <element name="is3D" type="boolean" use="required" />
          <element name="yearOfProduction" type="integer" use="required" />
          <element name="ageCategory" type="integer" use="required" />
          <element name="description" type="string" use="required" />
      </sequence>
      <attribute name="idOfMovie" type="integer" use="required"/>
  </complexType>
  </schema>
  ```

Now I wonder how to in these files put information about association in UML diagram. I read about "minOccurs" and "maxOccurs" but I don't know how and where put information about connection between classes

Comment: So you have a class structure and you want to design it's custom `xml`-based serialization format and you want to describe the format using the [xsd schema language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29)? Or you have a class structure and you want to export it's `xmi` model for use by another `xmi`-compliant tool?

Comment: What about the other question of your homework http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574879/uml-into-json-schema-and-xsd ?